# in unity,I discovered something strange in the window that appeared when I clicked "Open in Import Activity Window."

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, timestamp, assets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os4VP.png)In Unity "
Open in Import Activity Window
" When I open the window, the date the asset was imported appears. When I check the timestamp, it shows that the asset was imported 277 days ago even if the project was created today. Is there something wrong??

Even if I try to create a new project, the same thing happens. Even if you refresh the package, it comes out the same!